# Word/Phrase for "process of falling of tiny particles off a bread/biscuit piece"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions

Please consider the situation:

A bread piece has some tiny particles which we see keep on removing off bread, or lying loosely on a surface after we remove it from that surface (These tiny particles are called 'bread crumbs').

Suppose I have to say a sentence for a biscuit piece/bread piece, such as:

"Don't put these biscuits/cookies/bread pieces directly on bed sheet as it will/it is _________. Better put it on a plate and then eat."

Please suggest a word/phrase in a context related to a process of removal of something (such as tiny particles falling apart off a biscuit, or a bread piece).

The word 'crumbs' can be used here, but I am not able to fit it here.

I am unable to find a proper way to frame this sentence. Please suggest any other way to interpret this situation.

Comment: "it will *leave* crumbs" is how I usually say it.

Comment: _Gluten dandruff_ is one way to refer to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Don't put these biscuits/cookies/bread pieces directly on bedsheet as
> *they* will **[crumble](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/crumble)**. Better put it on a plate and then eat."

That's the way the cookie crumbles!

Answer (score 4):

I think you want [Crumbly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crumbly), meaning that the [cookies] are highly likely to crumble  (produce crumbs).

If you'd prefer something unrelated to "crumbs", you could use [Fragile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fragile), but while appropriate it doesn't work nearly as well.

Comment: Crumbly fits well here. But if the biscuit is not much crumbly. it's just that some tiny pieces keep falling apart from it. Then?

Comment: I am guessing you mean that the biscuit is not likely to break into large pieces but is likely to shed smaller crumbs? In this case, "crumbly" is still appropriate, though you could use "flaky" or "messy" if you aren't comfortable with "crumbly".

Comment: @a.s. You could say "*This biscuit is really [crummy](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/crummy?showCookiePolicy=true)*!". Heh heh heh.